# Session is not working + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am using express-session in my app. What i have tried is (POC):.

**server.js**

```
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'pal!lap789',
        // create new redis store.
        store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
        saveUninitialized: false, 
        key: 'user_sid',   
        resave: false,
        cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false }
    }));
app.get('/abcd', sessionChecker, function(req, res){
    res.send("hiiiii");
});

app.get('/session', (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = "subbuvlb@gmail.com";
    res.send("hgdhjdgjds")
});
```

Its working properly,

But when i  try to integrate with my project ,its not working.

```
app.use(session({
            secret: 'pal!lap789',
            // create new redis store.
            store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
            saveUninitialized: false, 
            key: 'user_sid',   
            resave: false,
            cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false }
        }));
var usersRouter = require('./router/users');
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

**router/user.js**

```
const express = require('express');  -------------> New express instantiated.
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
req.session.user = "emailid"
});
```

What i am trying to achieve is `have to check if user session is there for each resquest`,

so i modified my server.js file as follows:

```
    app.use(session({
                    secret: 'pal!lap789',
                    // create new redis store.
                    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
                    saveUninitialized: false, 
                    key: 'user_sid',   
                    resave: false,
                    cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false }
                }));
        var usersRouter = require('./router/users');
        app.use('/users', usersRouter);
    var sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.session.user) --------------------------->Undefined
      if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) { 
          next();
      } else {
          res.redirect('/login');
      }    
    };
var usersRouter = require('./router/users');
app.use('/users',sessionChecker, usersRouter);
```

Why the req.user.undefined if i specify router files in server.js. I think i explained clearly, ready to give more input if needed. Please provide ur ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

define global variable in your `server.js` file

```
global.express = require('express'); 
global.app = express();
global.session = require('express-session');

 app.use(session({
                    secret: 'pal!lap789',
                    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
                    saveUninitialized: false, 
                    key: 'user_sid',   
                    resave: false,
                    cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false }
                }));

    var sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {

      if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) { 
          next();
      } else {
          res.redirect('/login');
      }    
    };

var usersRouter = require('./router/users');
app.use('/users',sessionChecker, usersRouter);
```

in your `router/user.js`

```
const router = express.Router(); // use global express defined in server.js

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.user = "emailid"
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still the req.session.user is `Undefined`

Comment: are you using passportjs ?

Comment: Yes , but for someother module.

Comment: Session is empty when trying to access req.session.user in router file, But fif i try to accsess req.session.user in server.js file its there. Why??

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the trick,

I am checking from `Angular.js`  front-end, by default Angular will not include `Cookies`, so i have set `{"withCredentials": "true"}` in each Request from Angular Front-end.